# Exception while converting json string to java object by Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm using Gson lib to deserialize the json stirng into Java object, but there is a error occurs.
below is the json string:

```
    {
        "pageInfo": [
          {
            "detail": "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}",
            "id": 4,
            "type": 0
          }]
    }
```

and the java class:

```
    public java.util.List pageInfo;
    class CreditDetailItem {
        public String id;
        public int type;
        public String detail;
    }
```

And then an exception thrown: **Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING** on the 'detail' property.

Is there any one can help me?

Comment: add the code where you try to convert the JSON into Java object.

Comment: Should `detail` not be another object? Possibly Gson is smart enough to notice you have an object encoded as a string.

Comment: try without quotes and slashes.. `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}` .

Comment: I think there is an issue in JSON string written in your code, check readyandroid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the JSON does not match the Java code. Here is the recommended way of doing it in JAVA.

```
class JSONWrapper {
    java.util.List<PageInfo> pageInfo = new java.util.ArrayList<PageInfo>();

    public void setPageInfo(java.util.List<PageInfo> pageInfo) {
        this.pageInfo = pageInfo;
    }
    public java.util.List<PageInfo> getPageInfo() {
        return pageInfo;
    }
}

class PageInfo {
    String id;
    int type;
    String detail;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }
    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your formatted `JSON` data.

```
{
    "pageInfo": [
      {
        "detail": {
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": "value2"
            },
        "id": 4,
        "type": 0
      }]
}
```

Try this `POJO` class,

```
public class ParsedData {

    List<CreditDetailItem> pageInfo = new ArrayList<CreditDetailItem>();

    class CreditDetailItem {
        public String id;
        public int type;
        public Detail detail;

        //getters and setters
    }

    public class Detail {
        public String key1;
        public String key2;

        //getters and setters
    }

}
```

To parse the `JSON`,

```
ParsedData parsedData = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ParsedData.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one it's working for me.

Add dependency in build.gradle if it is not there:

```
compile("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0")
```

This is your JSONObject:

```
{
    "pageInfo": [
      {
        "detail": "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}",
        "id": 4,
        "type": 0
      }
    ]
}
```

This is your pageinfo list model class:

```
public class MyModelList {

    public List<MyModel> pageInfo = new ArrayList();
}
```

This is for your pageinfo list item model class:

```
public class MyModel {
    public String id;
    public int type;
    public String detail;
}
```

This is the method where you can check gson to json and vice version conversion for individually item or list models:

```
private void myGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        //Convert to java objects
        MyModel mModel = gson.fromJson("{\n" +
                        "            \"detail\": \"{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"value1\\\",\\\"key2\\\":\\\"value2\\\"}\",\n" +
                        "            \"id\": 4,\n" +
                        "            \"type\": 0\n" +
                        "          }"
                , MyModel.class);

        MyModelList mModelList = gson.fromJson("{\n" +
                        "        \"pageInfo\": [\n" +
                        "          {\n" +
                        "            \"detail\": \"{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"value1\\\",\\\"key2\\\":\\\"value2\\\"}\",\n" +
                        "            \"id\": 4,\n" +
                        "            \"type\": 0\n" +
                        "          }" +
                        "]\n" +
                        "    }"
                , MyModelList.class);
        Log.e("TAG", mModel.toString());
        Log.e("TAG", mModelList.toString());

        //Convert to JSON
        String sModelList = gson.toJson(mModelList);
        String sModel = gson.toJson(mModel);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

public class CreditDetailItem {

@SerializedName("pageInfo")
@Expose
public List pageInfo = new ArrayList();


public class PageInfo {

@SerializedName("detail")
@Expose
public String detail;

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
public Integer id;

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
public Integer type;
}

}